# How can I read NCSS files in R?

Tags: r

My lecturer uses NCSS and I want to use R to read the NCSS files, how can I read them?

They are in two parts `*.s0` and `*.s1`, examples about sport: [S0](https://noppa.aalto.fi/noppa/kurssi/mat-2.3112/viikkoharjoitukset/Mat-2_3112_kymmenot2__ncss_.s0) and [S1](https://noppa.aalto.fi/noppa/kurssi/mat-2.3112/viikkoharjoitukset/Mat-2_3112_kymmenot2__ncss_.s1).

Comment: A quick google did not yield much information. Could you provide a bit of background about these files? Are they binary, ascii? In addition, I think is much more suitable for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found a couple of these files by googling (would have been nice if you could have pointed us to some) and renaming them to .xls meant they could be opened in OpenOffice - from there you could save to CSV format and read into R.

It seems that the .s0 file is the column headers, and the .s1 file is the data, but I only looked at a very simple example.

I also tried a couple of the cross-platform Excel-spreadsheet-reading packages from CRAN (xlsx and XLConnect) and they both complained with:

```
w=loadWorkbook("./draft_70.s0.xls")
Error: IllegalArgumentException (Java): Your InputStream was neither an OLE2 stream, nor an OOXML stream
```

which makes me think they are a very old Excel format. How old is Excel 4? Anyway, you might be able to read them into MS Office, but Microsoft have a worse record at reading their old formats than OpenOffice do!

Comment: Excel 4.0 came out in 1992...hmmmm...that's even before the first version of R...

Comment: Have you tried our suggestions of reading them into MS Office or OpenOffice and saving them in a format R can read, such as CSV?

Answer (score 3):

From the user manual of NCSS:

> Each of these files is actually a Microsoft Excel 4.0 compatible spreadsheet file. This is where the 
>   row and column limits come from since an Excel 4.0 spreadsheet can contain up to 256 columns 
>   and 16,384 rows. We have used this format because it is popular, transportable, and because it 
>   allows us to provide a familiar, spreadsheet-style interface complete with formatting and 
>   formulas

You could try opening the file in MS Excel, or in NCSS for that matter, save it to a csv file and then reading it into R using read.csv. More information on the file format of NCSS can be found in [the manual](http://www.ncss.com/pdf/manuals/NCSSUG1.pdf), from page 102-5 onwards.